# Nested properties for structs with unknown property names?

Tags: go

I'm using JSON to get some values into a variable from an external source.

I have a type like this that [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/json#Unmarshal) puts values into:

```
    type Frame struct {
        Type  string
        Value map[string]interface{}
    }

    var data Frame
```

After unmarshal, I can access a the type by: `data.Type`

but if I try doing something like:

```
    if data.Type == "image" {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", data.Value.Imagedata)
    }
```

The compiler complains about no such value `data.Value.Imagedata`.

So my question is, how do I reference properties in Go that I know will be there depending on some condition?

Doing this works:

```
    type Image struct {
        Filename string
    }

    type Frame struct {
        Type  string
        Value map[string]interface{}
    }
```

But that isn't very flexible as I will be receiving different `Value`s.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`json.Unmarshal` will do its best to place the data where it best aligns with your type. Technically your first example will work, but you are trying to access the `Value` field with dot notation, even though you declared it to be a map:

This should give you some form of output:

```
if data.Type == 'image'{
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.Value["Imagedata"])
}
```

… considering that "Imagedata" was a key in the JSON.

You have the option of defining the type as deeply as you want or expect the structure to be, or using an `interface{}` and then doing type assertions on the values. With the `Value` field being a map, you would always access the keys like `Value[key]`, and the value of that map entry is an `interface{}` which you could type assert like `Value[key].(float64)`.

As for doing more explicit structures, I have found that you could either break up the objects into their own types, or define it nested in one place:

#### Nested (with anonymous struct)

```
type Frame struct {
    Type  string
    Value struct {
        Imagedata string `json:"image_data"`
    }
}
```

#### Seperate structs

```
type Frame struct {
    Type    string
    Value   value 
}

type value struct {
    Imagedata string `json:"image_data"`
}
```

I'm still learning Go myself, so this the extent of my current understanding :-).

Comment: Ah!  Man, that was simple.  Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Its rare that I see a Go question on here that I can manage to answer before the Go geniuses get to it.