# Unmarshaling nested JSON objects

Tags: json, go

There are [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101954/go-json-unmarshal-nested-object-into-string-or-byte) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452897/how-to-decode-json-with-type-convert-from-string-to-float64-in-golang) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801312/golang-nested-properties-for-structs-with-unknown-property-names) on the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674059/how-to-access-deeply-nested-json-keys-and-values) but none of them seem to cover my case, thus I'm creating a new one.

I have JSON like the following:

```
{"foo":{ "bar": "1", "baz": "2" }, "more": "text"}
```

Is there a way to unmarshal the nested bar property and assign it directly to a struct property without creating a nested struct?

The solution I'm adopting right now is the following:

```
type Foo struct {
    More String `json:"more"`
    Foo  struct {
        Bar string `json:"bar"`
        Baz string `json:"baz"`
    } `json:"foo"`
    //  FooBar  string `json:"foo.bar"`
}
```

This is a simplified version, please ignore the verbosity. As you can see, I'd like to be able to parse and assign the value to

```
//  FooBar  string `json:"foo.bar"`
```

I've seen people using a map, but that's not my case. I basically don't care about the content of `foo` (which is a large object), except for a few specific elements.

What is the correct approach in this case? I'm not looking for weird hacks, thus if this is the way to go, I'm fine with that.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for - https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/json/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Is there a way to unmarshal the nested bar property and assign it directly to a struct property without creating a nested struct?

No, encoding/json cannot do the trick with ">some>deep>childnode" like encoding/xml can do.
Nested structs is the way to go.

Comment: Why is this different than encoding/xml?

Comment: @CalebThompson The structure for XML and JSON are completely different, even if the simple cases look alike. The content of a XML tag is kinda:(An ordered map of sub-tags OR Text) AND an unordered map of attributes. JSON is much more like a Go struct. So mapping JSON to structs is much simpler: Just model the struct after your JSON.

Comment: in my case the structure of JSON is not actually decided so I can create a struct and when I parse it using map of [string]interface{}, I am having issues for nested elements. What can be done.?

Comment: But why we cannot unmarshal to struct inside struct?

Answer (score 52):

Like what Volker mentioned, nested structs is the way to go. But if you **really** do not want nested structs, you can override the UnmarshalJSON func.

https://play.golang.org/p/dqn5UdqFfJt

```
type A struct {
    FooBar string // takes foo.bar
    FooBaz string // takes foo.baz
    More   string 
}

func (a *A) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {

    var f interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(b, &f)

    m := f.(map[string]interface{})

    foomap := m["foo"]
    v := foomap.(map[string]interface{})

    a.FooBar = v["bar"].(string)
    a.FooBaz = v["baz"].(string)
    a.More = m["more"].(string)

    return nil
}
```

Please ignore the fact that I'm not returning a proper error.  I left that out for simplicity.

UPDATE: Correctly retrieving "more" value.

Comment: I'm getting &{FooBar:1 FooBaz:2 More:}. "Text" is missing

Comment: @GuySegev I went ahead and updated my answer to fix that issue.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 30):

This is an example of how to unmarshall JSON responses from the Safebrowsing v4 API sbserver proxy server:  https://play.golang.org/p/4rGB5da0Lt

```
// this example shows how to unmarshall JSON requests from the Safebrowsing v4 sbserver
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
)

// response from sbserver POST request
type Results struct {
    Matches []Match     
}

// nested within sbserver response
type Match struct {
    ThreatType string 
    PlatformType string 
    ThreatEntryType string 
    Threat struct {
        URL string
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    // sample POST request
    //   curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
    // -d '{"threatInfo": {"threatEntries": [{"url": "http://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/apiv4/ANY_PLATFORM/MALWARE/URL/"}]}}' 
    // http://127.0.0.1:8080/v4/threatMatches:find

    // sample JSON response
    jsonResponse := `{"matches":[{"threatType":"MALWARE","platformType":"ANY_PLATFORM","threatEntryType":"URL","threat":{"url":"http://testsafebrowsing.appspot.com/apiv4/ANY_PLATFORM/MALWARE/URL/"}}]}`

    res := &Results{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonResponse), res)
        if(err!=nil) {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n",res)
    fmt.Printf("\tThreat Type: %s\n",res.Matches[0].ThreatType)
    fmt.Printf("\tPlatform Type: %s\n",res.Matches[0].PlatformType)
    fmt.Printf("\tThreat Entry Type: %s\n",res.Matches[0].ThreatEntryType)
    fmt.Printf("\tURL: %s\n",res.Matches[0].Threat.URL)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing that json.Unmarshal *can* unmarshal a complex deeply nested json data. My problem was I was reading JSON from a file and ended up with some zero padding. Glad you shared this!

Answer (score 28):

Yes. With [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) all you have to do now is:

`bar := gjson.Get(json, "foo.bar")`

`bar` could be a struct property if you like. Also, no maps.

Comment: [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson) also allows the same trick:

`fastjson.GetString(json, "foo", "bar")`

Comment: just was I was looking for, easy and simple to use

Comment: Great library, thanks for introducing it!

Answer (score 10):

Assign the values of nested `json` to struct until you know the underlying type of json keys:-

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Object
type Object struct {
    Foo map[string]map[string]string `json:"foo"`
    More string `json:"more"`
}

func main(){
    someJSONString := []byte(`{"foo":{ "bar": "1", "baz": "2" }, "more": "text"}`)
    var obj Object
    err := json.Unmarshal(someJSONString, &obj)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("jsonObj", obj)
}
```

Comment: If only this worked with `kubebuilder`!

Comment: @ivandov  Tell me what is required for your code to work ?

Answer (score 9):

What about anonymous fields? I'm not sure if that will constitute a "nested struct" but it's cleaner than having a nested struct declaration. What if you want to reuse the nested element elsewhere?

```
type NestedElement struct{
    someNumber int `json:"number"`
    someString string `json:"string"`
}

type BaseElement struct {
    NestedElement `json:"bar"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something like this. But is working only with structures generated from proto.
https://github.com/flowup-labs/grpc-utils

in your proto

```
message Msg {
  Firstname string = 1 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "name.firstname"];
  PseudoFirstname string = 2 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "lastname"];
  EmbedMsg = 3  [(gogoproto.nullable) = false, (gogoproto.embed) = true];
  Lastname string = 4 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "name.lastname"];
  Inside string  = 5 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "name.inside.a.b.c"];
}

message EmbedMsg{
   Opt1 string = 1 [(gogoproto.jsontag) = "opt1"];
}
```

Then your output will be

```
{
"lastname": "Three",
"name": {
    "firstname": "One",
    "inside": {
        "a": {
            "b": {
                "c": "goo"
            }
        }
    },
    "lastname": "Two"
},
"opt1": "var"
}
```

Comment: Add few lines to explain how this answers the question. If the repo is deleted there is no value left in the answer.

Comment: I don't think he's coming back, mates.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but trying to help by giving an example of `GitLab` `GraphQL API` `json` response and how to use it in Golang:

suppose we do an API request to GitLab with this request:

```
 query{
  projects{
    count,
    nodes{
     fullPath 
    }
  }
}
```

Which will give us a response like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "projects": {
      "count": 4,
      "nodes": [
        {
          "fullPath": "mygroup/proj1"
        },
        {
          "fullPath": "mygroup/proj2"
        },
        {
          "fullPath": "mygroup/proj3"
        },
        {
          "fullPath": "mygroup/proj4"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So in our response we can analyze and match the response with Go data types:

`data`: as the parent of all (root node)

`projects`: which holds a `map[string]int` `(count)` and a `[]map[string]string` `(nodes)`  which is a `slice`

Given this, we can create structs to map the response:

For the root node `data` we can create this struct:

```
type projectData struct {
    Data struct {   // because data can consist of other nested stuff
        projects    //a struct which represents the structure of the projects
    } `json:"data"` //just mapping names
}
```

And the struct which holds the actual data from the `projects` node in our API response:

```
type projects struct {
    Projects struct {
        Count int                 `json:"count"`
        Nodes []map[string]string `json:"nodes"`
    } `json:"projects"`
}
```

And to test all of this, here is the `json.Unmarshal` and the usage:

```
func projects(resp []byte){
 var p projectData  // variable of type root node struct
 if err := json.Unmarshal(resp &p); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
 }

 fmt.Println(p.Data.Projects.Count) // print out the total count of projects

 for _, v := range p.Data.Projects.Nodes { //loop over all projects and print  the fullPath field
        fmt.Println(v["fullPath"])

 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Combining map and struct allow unmarshaling nested JSON objects where the key is dynamic.
=> map[string]

For example: stock.json

```
{
  "MU": {
    "symbol": "MU",
    "title": "micro semiconductor",
    "share": 400,
    "purchase_price": 60.5,
    "target_price": 70
  },
  "LSCC":{
    "symbol": "LSCC",
    "title": "lattice semiconductor",
    "share": 200,
    "purchase_price": 20,
    "target_price": 30
  }
}
```

Go application

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Stock struct {
    Symbol        string  `json:"symbol"`
    Title         string  `json:"title"`
    Share         int     `json:"share"`
    PurchasePrice float64 `json:"purchase_price"`
    TargetPrice   float64 `json:"target_price"`
}
type Account map[string]Stock

func main() {
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("stock.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var account Account
    log.Println(account)
}
```

The dynamic key in the hash is handle a string, and the nested object is represented by a struct.

Comment: this seems incomplete. raw is unused

Comment: At this code better introduce new type for Symbol. It is not any string.
This also help maintain typed relation at account map.
```golang
type Account map[Symbol]Stock
```