# Embedding anonymous structs

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how to embed an anonymous struct within another struct, for json parsing purposes.

I have an "extras" map that contains different attributes dependent on various factors. This map is a field of a larger json blob. I'd like to fully model out the various possibilities of the "extras" map so I can avoid using type assertions. I would like to have the "extras" structs be separate from the base struct (the rest of the json). I know I can do something like this:

```
type TestObj1 struct {
    ExtraObj `json:"extras"`
}

type ExtraObj struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}
```

This works great, because the json parses exactly how I would expect, and I can directly access `Foo` like so `testObj1.Foo`. The problem with this method is that now I have 2 different structs per possible "extras" variation, instead of 1. So then I could try something like this:

```
type TestObj2 struct {
    Extras struct {
        Foo string `json:"foo"`
    } `json:"extras"`
}
```

This also parses the json as expected, and gets rid of the need for 2 structs per variation. But the problem is, to access `Foo`, I need to go through `Extras` like so `testObj2.Extras.Foo`. I was hoping for a best of both worlds solution like so:

```
type TestObj3 struct {
    struct {
        Foo string `json:"foo"`
    } `json:"extras"`
}
```

But this is a compile error. A quick [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/965iYHBEdn) I put together for this.

Is there any way to accomplish something like this, or is it not possible in the language? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot do it, refer to [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21268855). Possible duplicate.

Comment: Disallowed by the language.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
type TestObj1 struct {
    ExO ExtraObj `json:"extras"`
}

type ExtraObj struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}
```

I did not test it myself, but should work.