# go unmarshaling nested json from http.get

Tags: json, go

I have read [Unmarshaling nested JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268000/unmarshaling-nested-json-objects)
but I am still unsure how to handle the json:

```
{
   "input":{
      "lat":1234,
      "lon":1234
   },
   "stuff":[
      {
         "soc":"510950802051011",
         "bbox":[
            -76.743917,
            37.298812,
            -76.741184,
            37.300357
         ],
         "ccn":"51095",
         "name":"James",
         "age":"51",
         "gf":"Mary",
         "state":"NYC",
         "pea":"PEA033",
         "rea":"REA002",
         "rpc":"RPC002",
         "vpc":"VPC002"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to only access stuff.ccn, stuff.name

```golang
    package main
    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"   
    )

     func main() {

        jStr := `{
   "input":{
      "lat":1234,
      "lon":1234
   },
   "stuff":[
      {
         "soc":"510950802051011",
         "bbox":[
            -76.743917,
            37.298812,
            -76.741184,
            37.300357
         ],
         "ccn":"51095",
         "name":"James",
         "age":"51",
         "gf":"Mary",
         "state":"NYC",
         "pea":"PEA033",
         "rea":"REA002",
         "rpc":"RPC002",
         "vpc":"VPC002"
      }
   ]
}`


        type Inner struct {
            Key2 []string `json:"ccn"`
            Key3 []string `json:"name"`
        }
        type Outer struct {
            Key Inner `json:"stuff"`
        }
        var cont Outer
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(jStr), &cont)        
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", cont)
    }
```

I think the issue I am having is with the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structs needs to follow what you have in JSON. In provided `jStr` where top level object maps to `Outer` you seem to have key `stuff` which is an array of `Inner` objects. You need to modify your types to reflect that like this:

```golang
    type Inner struct {
        Key2 string `json:"ccn"`
        Key3 string `json:"name"`
    }
    type Outer struct {
        Key []Inner `json:"stuff"`
    }
```

This basically says when `stuff` found take it as array and unmarshall each item as `Inner`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json-to-go-struct](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) one to get the go struct for your json.

Or simply use `var cont map[string]interface{}`